# What is the scope of "co-" in English?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prefixes

Is it right to refer to someone as a “co-chairwoman” if the other person doing the chairing is a man? Someone might say it is not, because the prefix “co-“ implies that two (or more) people share the same title. But in this case, the other person does not share the “chairwoman” title. On the other hand, someone might counter that “woman” is not really part of the title. It is just incidental. Where does the truth lie?

Comment: The term is _chair_, and it has no gender; rather, it has whatever gender the current chair cares to assign it. Why use a compound when a single syllable does the job? And in this case, _co-chair_.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to write it would be to use the genderless form, "co-chairperson". Because "chairperson" has no gender, it can refer to either a chairman or a chairwoman.

EDIT: Lumberjack made a good point in the comments - You can also use "co-chair", although it is a bit less formal.

Comment: That's a dodge.

Comment: You will often hear the less formal "co-chair" as well.

Comment: @juri - About 20% of good writing is dodging stuff.

Comment: No, juri, it's not a dodge. Good writing is the use of the clearest, the least awkward, and the most concise words. By trying to fit an awkward word like co-chairwoman into a spot where another word would work better?

Comment: Why? Because you have an interest in conveying that the person of whom you are speaking is a woman. Often times, this is relevant.